# Can I speed up code by moving typeof out of loops?

Tags: c#, performance, loops

I have code that executes `typeof` many times inside loops.

I'm wondering if I should call `typeof` outside the loops and use a variable?

My code is currently like this.

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Type t = Foo(i);
    if(t == typeof(string))
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Is the following code faster, slower or no difference?

```
Type s = typeof(string)
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Type t = Foo(i);
    if(t == s)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Instead of running a few C# tests to see which runs faster. I'm looking for an answer that can explain what happens when `typeof` is used.

Does it produce a compile time constant?

Comment: Hard to tell a *better* way with this particular example...

Comment: +1 @Jon thanks for the link. Looks like my assignment to a variable could actually be slower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No (as in extremely negligible), the `typeof()` is done at compile-time--the work is the type comparison.  What you should really be asking is why you're checking types when you could be using polymorphism.

Comment: +1 peter, regarding polymorphism, tho i guess the question is more the academics of the mecahnics

Comment: Polymorphism makes the "comparison" implicit to some degree--which could turn into a much quicker comparison (rather than the comparison of two objects)

Comment: Although this certainly sounds logical, it's just as obvious that in the general case only the jitter would be able to perform this optimization (the IL compiler cannot possibly reduce this to a constant because the type resides in a different assembly than your code). And to my knowledge there is absolutely no guarantee that it will do so.

Comment: @Curt could you detail what you mean, returning an object type in my mind isn't "polymorphism."

Comment: @Jon even if the jitter couldn't "optimize" it, it's still no longer an object comparison.

Comment: I'm working on code that only processes C# types. There is no data. Or well the type is the data. I understand polymorphism but I don't think it applies to my performance question.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: When did the type of the comparison's arguments come into the discussion? And what do you mean "an object comparison"?

Comment: It's what it is. Just a very basic loop calling a function that does something when a string type is found.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Hard to tell whether it would, you haven't provided enough detail to know what you're doing with the type.  Based on the example there is not reason to compare type because nothing you've show would make Foo() return a different type on each iteration.

Comment: @Jon Compare an object of type Type to another object of type Type.  To be clear, that's "optimized" into a token load, a call to GetTypeFromHandle, and a comparison.

Comment: @PeterRitchie well sorry, I'll change `Foo()` to `Foo(i)`.

Comment: ...as opposed to a virtual table lookup.

Comment: @Curt, you can't really do "polymorphism" with Type or typeof

Comment: @Curt I'm not sure what you mean by " typeof() would have to be evaluated for each loop".  `typeof(string)` always returns the same thing.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: No, that's just the IL that csc emits. Moreover, if we left it at that then your answer would obviously be wrong because csc in general does not perform many optimizations (it certainly does not perform this one). So it's all up to the jitter, who may recognize that `GetTypeFromHandle` is a known method and it's always called with the same argument and thus the call can be hoisted outside the loop body. Sorry, but this answer is too light on the facts.